# How to decrypt "KeyMaterial" in XML files

Tags: xml, encryption

Hi I was wondering how do you decrypt the "keymaterial" from an xml file do see the wifi password? And is it also possible to copy the needed file from the "wlansvc" folder onto my own computer and access the network through my computer? And if that does work, can't i use a network password recovery program on my own computer as i have full admin rights, therefore i can see the password?

Any reply would be appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you only want to get the Password and you were connected once you must write in cmd.exe:
netsh wlan show profiles
choose the one you want to get connected and command:
netsh wlan show profile [Wlan name] key=clear
Now you can see the password.
That works for most of the other deconnected Wlans you were connected before.
To see which that are you must only give the command:
netsh wlan show all
Now you can see in which wlan this device was connected before.

Answer (score -1):

The response above helped me, but with a little correction:

The syntax is

```
 wlan show profile name="<PROFILE_NAME>" key=clear
```

(No brackets.)

Especially relevant if your wifi name contains spaces.
If you know the exact name of the wifi profile you're looking for, you can directly use this one, too. If you don't, as user Starter instructed, the first command will list them all.